# Selecting features within certain buffer distance of selected feature using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, line, select-by-location, proximity

I have a shapefile of thousands of polylines. I have select one feature, I want to select all other features that is within say 100m of the selected feature.

How do I achieve it by pyqgis?

[image]

Comment: Is the one feature selected using a mouseclick or from code?

Comment: it is from code, say select where fid = 1

Comment: Do you want the 100m tolerance to be set from the selected feature's centre, bounding box rectangle, or as an actual 100m buffer from the line (note increasing order of complexity).

Comment: i want it to be the buffer

Comment: I posted a code with the "buffer" requirement of your selected feature.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: @chenghopan - Could you please provide some basic code for this question to keep it open? :)

Comment: Before improving your question with the addition of code be sure to review this Meta Q&A https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4650/115.  The closure here is just saying to you and future askers of similar questions that a code snippet that illustrates what they have tried is requested at the outset and needed for it to remain open for new answers.  It and its answers should remain here even without code being added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to select all features that are within 100 m of the selected "buffer" feature you can use next code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

#selected feature fid = 0
geom_buffer = feats[0].geometry().buffer(100, -1)

#erasing selected feature in original list
del feats[0]

new_feats = [feat for feat in feats
             if feat.geometry().intersects(geom_buffer) ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "LineString?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'line',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(new_feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])

prov.addFeatures(new_feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

It produces a memory layer with features that match this condition.

I tried out above code with next line layer; where selected feature (id=0) was previously visualized as buffer by using its WKT format into QuickWKT plugin of QGIS.

[image]

After running the code, memory layer (red layer in next image) was obtained as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This should give you some ideas.

```
lyr = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
featDict = {feature.id(): feature for (feature) in lyr.getFeatures()}  #stores features in a dictionary for fast access
featIdx = QgsSpatialIndex(lyr.getFeatures())   #spatial index for faster spatial queries
bufDist = 100                                  #sets distance

for line in lyr.selectedFeatures():
    xyList = line.geometry().asPolyline()
    minx = min([xy[0] for xy in xyList])   #minimum x-coordinate
    maxx = max([xy[0] for xy in xyList])   #maximum x-coordinate
    miny = min([xy[1] for xy in xyList])   #minimum y-coordinate
    maxy = max([xy[1] for xy in xyList])   #maximum y-coordinate
    ids = featIdx.intersects(QgsRectangle(minx - bufDist, miny - bufDist, maxx + bufDist, maxy + bufDist))

    #lyr.selectByIds(ids)  #use this if you don't need total accuracy, much faster!!

    #For QGIS versions below 2.16        
    for id in ids:
        if featDict[id].geometry().distance(line.geometry()) < bufDist:
            lyr.select(id)

    #For QGIS 2.16 or above
    tids = []  #true ids of nearby features that we want to select
    for id in ids:
        if featDict[id].geometry().distance(line.geometry()) < bufDist:
            tids.append(id)
    lyr.selectByIds(tids, 1)   #AddToSelection, see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2dbfa880644f08f8b9f77b6c28036c74 for SelectBehaviour
```

Comment: it says QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'selectByIds', any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you're probably using a version older than 2.16 (see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a927ae6e3e40ff37ed2a0d104fe6ff242). Hold on, I'll edit the code :).

Comment: what is the caution comment about ? Is it exceed the extent?

Comment: Yeah, I need to fix that actually. It's not exactly the minimum y-coordinate, the code just uses the y-coordinate from the node with the minimum x-coordinate. So if you have a complex zig-zagging line, that won't quite work.

Comment: yeah... I just added a pic of my data

Comment: Cool, it should work now, though it's not very optimized for speed. The picture definitely helps, I can see now why you want a buffer check ;)

Comment: it gives an error : NameError: name 'xyList' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy and paste that line in... Let me know if there's any other problems.