# Defining features geometry in new created layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, point, geometry

I'm trying to create points in a new layer with a given distance along all lines of another layer.

Here my function so far:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature, QgsGeometry,
                   QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry,
                   QgsField, QGis)
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import math

def pointsAlongLine(dist):
  try:
    inputlayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('route')[0]
    print ('route-layer found')
    sum = 0
    sumdistances = []
    epsg = inputlayer.crs().postgisSrid()
    uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"
    memlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'itpoint', 'memory')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(memlayer)
    iface.setActiveLayer(inputlayer)
    inputlayer.selectAll()
    feat = inputlayer.selectedFeatures()
    for f in feat:
      length = f.geometry().length()
      print(length)
      for sum in range (0, (math.ceil(length) - dist), dist):
        sumdistances.append(sum)
      geompoints = [f.geometry().interpolate(distance).exportToWkt()
                       for distance in range (0, (math.ceil(length) - dist), dist)]
      memlayer.startEditing()
      prov = memlayer.dataProvider()
      feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(sumdistances)) ]
      for i, ft in enumerate(feats):
        ft.setAttributes([i])
        if i>(len(geompoints) -1):
            break
        ft.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(geompoints[i]))
      prov.addFeatures(feats)
      memlayer.commitChanges()
      memlayer.updateExtents()
  except IndexError:
    print ('route does not exist')
```

It seems that all works fine (layer is created and all points calculated and set correctly) but now I realized, that the new created points don't have their geometry defined.

How do I manage that and give them point geometries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function create **a lot** of empty geometries and is way too much complicated.
Here is a way to do this with the same approach but without some useless steps + some lines to transfer an attribute to the memlayer...

```
def pointsAlongLine(dist):
  try:
    inputlayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('ADR_ROUTE__LineString')[0]
    print ('route-layer found')
    epsg = inputlayer.crs().postgisSrid()
    uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&index=yes"
    memlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'itpoint', 'memory')
    prov = memlayer.dataProvider()
    prov.addAttributes([QgsField("NAMETEXT", QVariant.String)])
    memlayer.startEditing()
    for f in inputlayer.getFeatures():
      value = f.attribute('NAMETEXT')
      print value
      length = f.geometry().length()
      for distance in range (0, (int(length)), dist):
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(f.geometry().interpolate(distance))
        feat.setAttributes([value])   #be careful with the order of the attributes in the list if you add more than one...
        prov.addFeatures([feat])
    memlayer.commitChanges()
    memlayer.updateExtents()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(memlayer)
  except IndexError:
    print ('route does not exist')
```

Let me now and if it's working well

Comment: You're awesome! it's remarkably faster without the useless steps (I couldn't see) :D

Comment: @store attributes: is not necessary but because you ask ;-) how could I copy and past a column of the inputlayer into the new memlayer?

Comment: What is the name of the attribute of input layer and the type?

Comment: with the attribute "NAMETEXT" are the names of the streets saved (I don't know where to look up which type it is, but therefore it should be a string).

Comment: I have edit my answer to add attributes NAMETEXT in the memlayer

Comment: wish I gonna get someday the skills you have! :-) Thx for your help!

Comment: @Nico Glad to help!